# How Do We Get the Throwable After retryWhen() Stops Retrying?

Tags: rx-java2

```
  private String stringResult=null;
  private Throwable throwableResult=null;

  @Test
  public void whereIsTheThrowable() {
    Observable.just("foo")
      .map(this::justBlowUp)
      .retryWhen(errors -> errors.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (n, i) -> i))
      .subscribe(s -> stringResult=s, throwable -> throwableResult=throwable);

    assertNull(stringResult);
    assertNotNull(throwableResult);
  }

  private String justBlowUp(String s) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }
```

That test fails with RxJava 2.1.7. `retryWhen()` appears to consume the `Throwable`, even after it no longer retries. The `subscribe()` lambda does not get any `Throwable`. While this test is silly (`justBlowUp()` just blows up), you can imagine an `Observable` chain where the work usually succeeds, only occasionally fails, and seldom fails four times in succession. However, in that case, it would be useful to have the `Throwable` for logging purposes.

`retryUntil()` does allow `subscribe()` to get the final `Throwable`... but then in `retryUntil()` we do not have the `Throwable` at all and cannot make decisions on it (e.g., retry N times if it seems to be an Internet connectivity error, but fail fast for everything else). `retryWhen()` seems to be the more powerful option, but how do we get the final `Throwable`, after `retryWhen()` stops retrying?

I could use a field to hold the `Throwable`, set inside the `retryWhen()` logic, but it feels like there should be a more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`retryWhen` treats the handler's completion as indicator for completing normally, therefore, the handler should fail after the retry options have been exhausted:

```java
Observable.just("foo")
.map(this::justBlowUp)
.retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(new Function<Throwable, Observable<Integer>>() {
    int count;
    @Override
    public Observable<Integer> apply(Throwable error) {
        if (count++ < 3) {
            return Observable.just(count);
        }
        return Observable.error(error);
    }
}))
.test()
.assertFailure(RuntimeException.class);
```

Comment: I am calling `doOnError` after `retryWhen`, but it is not executed whereas `doOnComplete` is executed. why is that?

Comment: @sansari How should I know without seeing your actual code? Does `doOnError` execute **before** retryWhen?